# (Image) Does this mean I have the right video drivers installed?

Tags: drivers, graphics, gpu-driver, ubuntu-mate

[image: My current driver data]

When I first installed Ubuntu Mate, weeks ago, on this new laptop, video card drivers were clearly not present, since games ran very poorly and certain ones reported "no hardware acceleration available".

But now, this window shows me that drivers ARE being used, but my games aren't performing any better at all.

Comment: System specs? Do you also have an integrated GPU (that the CPU provides?)

Comment: Sincerely, AMD drivers s**k. Have you already tried using the proprietary drivers? They are usually better. Or stick with Intel/NVidia.

Comment: @EduardoCola How do I do that? How do I change it?

Comment: To switch to proprietary drivers just select one of them (the fglrx proprietary should be the best) and apply your settings. This may take a long time (like 15-20 minutes) and you'll have to reboot to apply the driver changes. To stick with Intel or NVidia, well, you'll have to buy new hardware.

Answer (score 0):

The open-source driver does not have the same performance than the proprietary driver. Prefer this last one (fglrx driver) if you want the best performance for your games.